# Add field to edit user in voyager

Tags: html, css, laravel, input-field, voyager

> **I added a Custom Field in User table named Wallet. which I want to edit from Admin panel. But the Wallet  field is not showing on the Edit user page. How can I add the Wallet Input field on Edit user page?**

**This is Table:**
[image]

**Here is the User edit page**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is some sort of a bug in Voyager. I could reproduce your issue.
I found a solution here: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/1392

Follow what **owldesign** commented on Jun 29, 2018

That should work for you too.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Doing this -> https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3215
and then your solution Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add custom view for user add edit. The following structure is to make it work.
resources/views/vendor/voyager/users/edit-add.php